# Is it possible to create DEMs from ORT format in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, dem

I recently requested DEMs for my area of interest.  The data has however arrived in ORT file format - how do I create DEMs from this data in QGIS?  When I open the files in Notepad there are three columns which respectively contain x and y co-ordinates in m (Hartebeeshoek Lo31) and a third column containing the height value.

Comment: Do you want to create a raster or a TIN?

Comment: I would like to create a raster

Answer (score 1):

Try the 'Add Delimited Text Layer' plugin (blue rectangle). With that plugin you can create a point-layer which you then can use directly or you can rasterize using the vector to raster option.

Comment: Thanks, tried this, but it didn't work unfortunately.